# watchOS app uses different app icon on the home screen than in the App Switcher

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, xcasset

I'm using the watchOS simulator in order to test my app. For some reason, the system uses an older app icon in the App Switcher than the one being displayed on the home screen, despite my .appiconset containing the same resized image multiple times. What causes this and how can I make the correct icon show up?

[image: Screenshot of the correct and incorrect app icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a caching issue and you should erase all Simulator content and settings in order to see the correct icon again by navigating to **Simulator.app/Device/Erase All Content and Settings...**

However, personally, I wouldn't worry about this too much, since it's a watchOS bug, not something wrong in your project settings.